# Where is the debug.keystore on Mac?

Tags: android, macos, google-maps, xamarin.android

I'm trying to generate my fingerprint and it supposed to be here : `~/.android/debug.keystore`, but I don't have nothing there, although I can run my monodroid projects normally as well, so how can I find the debug.keystore file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Mono for Android `debug.keystore` file is in `$HOME/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android`. (Yes, there are spaces in that directory name.)

Comment: i realise that my problem was my apiKey, i got my fingerprint from another directory: ~/.android/debug.keystore and i didnt think that was the problem, because i generate with it in order to obtain my apikey and i use it in my Java android app and was working fine, but then i try change it to the debug.store that is located in this directory: $HOME/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore, and throws me another fingerprint, so i use it to generate another apikey, and then magically works my app on Mono. Despite of thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 83):

The debug.keystore is in the folder that you say, but it's hidden so you can't see it on Finder.

Open a terminal and type:

```
cd ~/.android/
ls
```

If you could see the debug.keystore, that's the right folder.
If you need to open in Finder, type in the same folder:

```
open .
```

Regards.

Answer (score 14):

Path with get SHA1 on android studio from command prompt

**keytool -list -v -keystore {complete path to debug.keystore} -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android**

**Example:-**

**keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android**

Comment: This saved the day for me!

Answer (score 10):

Simply you can open Finder then you can go through following path.

Go -> Home -> ./android/debug.keystore

Make sure that you can see the hidden files and folders.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open Finder
2. select menu **Go** -> **Go To Folder...**
3. type /Users/username/.android

Answer (score 4):

You will find debug.keystore file here,
fire this command in terminal to see hidden file

1. `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`
2. Go to home directory
3. go to .android folder which will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

For mac path, you have to create another file called `debug.key.properties`, it paste the following 4 lines inside it (and don't forget to adjust it with your values):

```
storePassword=yourPassword
keyPassword=yourKeyPassword
keyAlias=yourKeyAlias
storeFile=//Users//test//Desktop//project//Debug//debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

**2024**: I had this problem on MacOS Sonoma with Android Studio Hedgehog. ./android/debug.keystore.lock exists but no debug.keystore. Deleting .android does not help. I think there is some Apple system holding an outdated version of this file. Its not Keychain :-(

```
Symptom: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
```

Solution: create the file with keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore ...