# Unable to find keystore for android on Mac

Tags: android, macos, flutter, gradle, keystore

I am using flutter to develop an application for which I need the SHA-1.
i opened the signing report on gradle but it said missing keystore.
Using "keytool -alias "AndroidDebugKey" -genkeypair" but I am unable to find the keystore on the system.
I tried this again but it shows
java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias  already exists.
I also did % keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android but I got this error
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: did you try using `./gradlew signingReport` in your android folder

Comment: yes I did that as well and it shows the error Missing Keystore

Comment: what was the error with  `./gradlew signingReport`

Comment: Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508189/where-is-the-debug-keystore-on-mac

Comment: I tried keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android but I am getting keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:783)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:379)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:372)

Answer (score 0):

Open the flutter application in android studio -> Open for editing in Android Studio option

Then open Gradle, located in the right hand side -> android -> Tasks -> android -> signingReport

Now on the run window, you will get SHA-1

Comment: I did this before but when I open the signing report it says Missing Keystore

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode#:~:text=And%20you%20will%20see%20all%20you%20need%20to%20get%20google_maps_key%20.&text=Step%201%3A%20On%20Top%20Right,Studio%20Click%20On%20Gradle%20option.&text=Step%203%3A%20Click%20on%20the,can't%20run%20your%20project.